# Trouble dynamically resizing div elements based upon viewport width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a responsive design and I have a d3.js bar chart within this design. The bars' widths correspond to the width of the viewport. If the bar is 1/5, it is 20% of the viewport width, and so on. I'm trying to resize them dynamically, which they sort of do, but the code behaves very unlike what I'm trying to obtain. Since all of the divs are different widths, I thought I would run through each div with the class *bar-chart* and give it a new width by multiplying the ratio of new viewport / old viewport by its old width.

Here's my code:

```
var docFifth = ($(".row").width())/5;
var fullWidth = docFifth*5; //this is the full width of the viewport
$(window).resize(function(){
   var newSize = $(".row").width();
   var percentage = (newSize / fullWidth).toFixed(2);
   $(".bar-class").each(function(){
     $(this).width($(this).width() * percentage);
   })
});
```

What's wrong here? It almost seems to work initially but then exponentially gets too small. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use media queries?  Seems easier than what you're trying to do here manually.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: I don't think that would be as granular as I'm going for.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "granular", but Media Queries is one of the the most popular and easiest ways to make a web site responsive.  You're going about it the hard way.

Comment: I mean that I'd rather size it pixel-by-pixel, just like the rest of the website sizes when I change the viewport width. I'd have to put media queries every 25 pixels to retain that behavior, no?

Comment: Look at these examples.. you specify at what screen size you want the class to change, and its that simple:  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp